# I am not able to get the grid data in jmeter using post processor

Tags: testing, grid, jmeter, html-table

I am having jmeter to perform testing. However I have visited to some while doing the testing. when I have view the result of the same in that except the grid table data it shows the every details on the web page. I am having jmeter 3.0 installed on windows 10 64 bit.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks for replay
as you said i have change the path from "/ntes/specialTrains.jsp"
and made http request default as "enquiry.indianrail.gov.in"
Error message is not displayed, but still not able to get the grid in the output.
attached the screen shot please have look.

[image]

[image]

"Issue is still not resolved. so please assist for the same"

Comment: to get rid of the exception, change `Default value` from `Not found` to something url-friendly (e.g. `not_found`)
But to understand why your xpath not found, we would need to see the fragment of the page you are searching.

Comment: Hello I have tried as you said to understand the why not getting the value of spacial trains. now for the same error is displayed. screen shot is attached please check

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully getting your answer, however here is a couple of advices:

1. You won't be able to see the JMeter Variable originating from the XPath Extractor in the View Results Tree listener unless you add a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to your Test Plan. View Results Tree listener itself has `XPath Tester` mode where you can evaluate your XPath queries directly against the "live" response without having to re-run the request. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for above instructions explained in details.
2. Your 2nd request is misconfigured. It should look as follows:

   - Server Name or IP: `enquiry.ingianrail.gov.in`
   - Path: `/ntes/specialTrains.jsp`

     [image: HTTP Request Fixed]

   Actually the easiest way to get JMeter test script "skeleton" and avoiding errors like above is just recording it via JMeter's built-in proxy server. See [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide for instructions.